# Are the [arcgis-portal] and [portal] tags duplicates?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

It looks like there are two tags in GIS-SE that are related to the concept of *portal*:

> [ArcGIS-Portal](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-portal):
>
> Portal for ArcGIS allows you to share maps, applications, and other
>   geographic information with other people in your organization. The
>   content that you share is delivered through a website. You can
>   customize the website to fit your organization's look and feel.

---

> [Portal:](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/portal)
>
> *No description.*

---

**Are the `ArcGIS-Portal` and `Portal` tags duplicates?** Should the `Portal` tag be deleted?

Answer (score 3):

There were only two questions tagged [portal](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/portal):

- [Refining Features from Portal Webmap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/337695/refining-features-from-portal-webmap)
- [Active Directory Permissions for ArcGIS Enterprise](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/333485/active-directory-permissions-for-arcgis-enterprise)

I think both clearly related to ArcGIS for Portal, and so I am re-tagging them to be [arcgis-portal](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-portal).

That means the [portal](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/portal) tag (which has no tag wiki) will disappear within 24 hours, but can be re-created later if a case for it emerges.